# Evolution repeatedly reports "Unable to move deleted messages"

Tags: 17.10, email, evolution, imap

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 17.10 and set up evolution to synchronize with a mail account (IMAP) via outlook web access (OWA). Now, the following message pops up on every start (and also regularly thereafter as long as the application is running):

[image: error message in evolution stating that an unexpected server response took place attempting to move deleted messages]

I provided `CAMEL_DEBUG=all` to investigate the error further:

```
[...] # more logs
B00027 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.'
[imapx:B] got untagged response
[imapx:B] Have token 'EXISTS' id 3198
[imapx:B] imapx_untagged_exists: updating mailbox 'INBOX' messages: 3198 ~> 3198
[imapx:B] got untagged response
[imapx:B] Have token 'RECENT' id 0
[imapx:B] imapx_untagged_recent: updating mailbox 'INBOX' recent: 0 ~> 0
[imapx:B] got untagged response
[imapx:B] Have token 'FLAGS' id 0
[imapx:B] flags: 0000001f
[imapx:B] got untagged response
[imapx:B] Have token 'OK' id 0
[imapx:B] got untagged response
[imapx:B] Have token 'OK' id 0
[imapx:B] got untagged response
[imapx:B] Have token 'OK' id 0
[imapx:B] got untagged response
[imapx:B] Have token 'OK' id 0
[imapx:B] Got completion response for command 00027 'SELECT'
[imapx:B] camel_imapx_server_process_command_sync: 0x7f7af0010060 ~> (nil); success:1 local-error:[null] result:OK status-text:'SELECT completed.'
[imapx:B] adding command, format = 'UID MOVE '
[imapx:B] uidset add '9846'
[imapx:B]  start
[imapx:B] uidset add '9847'
[imapx:B] uidset add '9849'
[imapx:B]  :range
[imapx:B] adding command, format = '%u:%u'
[imapx:B] got gint '9846'
[imapx:B] got gint '9847'
[imapx:B] uidset add '9853'
[imapx:B]  ,next
[imapx:B] adding command, format = ','
[imapx:B] adding command, format = '%u'
[imapx:B] got gint '9849'
[imapx:B] uidset add '9854'
[imapx:B] uidset add '9855'
[imapx:B] adding command, format = ','
[imapx:B] adding command, format = '%u:%u'
[imapx:B] got gint '9853'
[imapx:B] got gint '9855'
[imapx:B] adding command, format = ' %M'
[imapx:B] completing command buffer is [39] 'UID MOVE 9846:9847,9849,9853:9855 Trash'
[imapx:B] camel_imapx_server_process_command_sync: (nil) () ~> 0x7f7af0010360 (MOVE_MESSAGE)
[imapx:B] Starting command ( literal) B00028 UID MOVE 9846:9847,9849,9853:9855 Trash
[imapx:B] I/O: 'B00028 UID MOVE 9846:9847,9849,9853:9855 Trash'
[imapx:B] I/O: '[COPYUID 346  ]
B00028 OK MOVE completed.'
[imapx:B] camel_imapx_server_process_command_sync: 0x7f7af0010360 ~> (nil); success:0 local-error:unexpected server response: result:[null] status-text:'[null]'
[imapx:B] Removed connection 0x7f7b8005b590 (server:0x555647a6ee00) due to error: Error moving messages: unexpected server response:
[imapx:B] I/O: ''
```

The receiving options for the defect account:

[image: account settings]

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've put this in the "answer" so I can add a screen shot.
This is how I have my Evolution / Outlook set up. I don't have the same issue as you, so experimenting with options may help.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I mirrored your settings but the problem persists. (I can not even issue to delete folders using the client; a similar error occurs)

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is for you to post images of all the "tabs", [Identity], [Receiving email] etc, I'll check against mine and post the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve a similar problem by setting up the Outlook Web Access as an Exchange Webservice in Evolution. Not what I wanted, because I experience some other flaws with it, but managing emails works.